# Python file descriptor open and close operation for uploading files by chunks

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on http file upload to server. To handle large files I'm using chunk upload, where files are divided into chunks of lets say 1MB and are sent to backend server synchronously as a POST request. At back-end bottle server,I receive chunk and append it to a new file using file.write.

```
@route('file_upload', method = 'POST')
def file_upload():
    file_content = request.body`enter code here`
    with open(dst_path,'ab') as dst_file_obj:
       dst_file_obj.write(file_content.read())
       dst_file_obj.close()
```

But opening and closing file descriptor everytime I receive chunks is an costly operation. Now how can I open a file on first chunk and close on receiving final chunk of bytes without opening and closing of every chunk I receive for a particular file ?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details, doesn't this work ?:

```
@route('file_upload', method = 'POST')
def file_upload():
    file_content = request.body`enter code here`
    with open(dst_path,'ab') as dst_file_obj:
       for chunk in file_content:
           dst_file_obj.write(chunk)
           # dst_file_obj.close() #< not needed gets closed when with is left
```

Comment: Here still we are opening the file for every chunk(request) of a file. My question is there a way we can open it once on first request(chunk) and next chunk onwards, we should not open the file again, instead we should be able to append until last chunk is received.

Comment: That is true if your chunks come by request.  How would you know what the last chunk is?  This looks as Flask to me ... maybe take a look at: https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/ ?